# Delivering deployment-specific information to Javascript

Tags: javascript, web-applications, deployment

Since UI is sometimes built with Javascript, I am curious about what people do to deliver properties that change between deployment instances of a web application. For instance, I have all static assets being served up from a different domain than where the webapp is being delivered (static.example.com vs example.com). In development, the static domain is different than what it is for production (dev.static.example for development vs static.example.com for a production deployment).

With Javascript, I end up building UI elements with img tags dynamically (as part of an ajax response, for example). The image src attr is going to be different in production vs development. I know of some ways to get this changing information to Javascript but nothing seems that great. I'm curious if anyone of you has any tips to deal with situations like this, or what best practices you've come up with.

Answer (score 0):

I would concentrate on using JSON + [jQuery templates](http://stephenwalther.com/blog/archive/2010/11/30/an-introduction-to-jquery-templates.aspx).

Comment: Then you'd be running your html templates through whatever framework's templating engine to dump the static url, right? I feel that is wrong.. somehow.

Comment: Argh, cut off. This was my first idea but I am still looking for something better, if possible.

Comment: You don't have to do it that way. Each page can have its own data-store. take a look at sencha.com's EXT framework.

Comment: That looks like widgets. What would I use in the library that would help me deliver a custom domain based on deployment?

Comment: It's not just widgets, it's the best, most well-thought-out and powerful JS framework available today. It uses JSON stores for everything, including configuring the UI. Swapping datasets for different sites or markets is simple.

Comment: This is definitely overkill for what I need. I don't need a widget framework. I am looking for opinions on how best to deliver a static asset domain.